# deduplicate dataframe index and merge columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following:

```
 t    len   id  accession
 t1   150   A   X1
 t1   150   B   X2
 t1   150   C   X3
 t2   200   E   X4
 t2   200   F   X5
 t2   200   G   X6
```

I want the following:

```
 t    len   id      accession
 t1   150   A,B,C   X1,X2,X3 
 t2   200   E,F,G   X4, X5,X6
```

Is there any way to pivot the dataframe as described by [pandas.DataFrame.pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), but at the same time merging the columns entries into a single column?

Answer (score 1):

My proposed solution combines `groupby` and `agg`. Let's start with the data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "t": ["t1", "t1", "t1", "t2", "t2", "t2"],
    "len": [150, 150, 150, 200, 200, 200],
    "id": ["A", "B", "C", "E", "F", "G"],
    "accession": ["X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6"]})
```

Solution

```
data.groupby(["t", "len"]).agg({"id": lambda x: ",".join(x), 
                                "accession": lambda x: ",".join(x)}).reset_index()
```

The output

```
    t  len     id accession
0  t1  150  A,B,C  X1,X2,X3
1  t2  200  E,F,G  X4,X5,X6
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)

By default, when you specify a function as an argument to `agg`, it's applied to *all* series that are *not* using for grouping. So you can simply use:

```
res = data.groupby(['t', 'len']).agg(','.join).reset_index()
```

If your dataframe has additional series you wish to ignore, you can specify series you wish to aggregate explicitly:

```
res = data.groupby(['t', 'len'])['id', 'accession'].agg(','.join).reset_index()
```